Equivalence of unconditional convergence
I have the following problem:
Let {$e_{\gamma}\,|\,\gamma\in\Gamma$} be a countable set in a banach-space $B$. The series $\sum_{\gamma\in\Gamma}e_\gamma$ is unconditionally convergent, if there is a limit $f\in B$ and $F_0\subset\Gamma$, such that
$$||f\,-\,\sum_{\gamma\in F}e_\gamma||<\epsilon$$
for all finite $F_0\subset F$.
I now need to show that this is equivalent to
$$\lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}||f-\sum_{k=1}^{N}e_{\pi(k)}||=0$$
for every permutation $\pi :\mathbb{N}\rightarrow\Gamma$
I have the "$\Rightarrow$" direction but I'm having problems with the other direction. I got the hint, that it can be shown by contradiction via induction.
Any help would be appreciated!

If the series is not unconditionally convergent, there exists some $\varepsilon > 0$ such that for any finite subset $F_{0}$ of $\Gamma$, there exists a finite subset $F$ of $\Gamma$ containing $F_{0}$ such that
$$\varepsilon \leq \left\| f - \sum_{\gamma\in F}e_{\gamma} \right\|.$$
Fix such an $\varepsilon$. The condition above can be used to obtain a sequence $(F_{n})_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ of strictly increasing finite subsets of $\Gamma$ such that $\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}F_{n} = \Gamma$ and
$$\varepsilon \leq \left\| f - \sum_{\gamma\in F_{n}}e_{\gamma} \right\|$$
for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$.
Then it is possible to construct a permutation $\pi :\mathbb{N} \to \Gamma$ such that for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$, there exists some $\phi (n)\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $\pi (\{1, \ldots , \phi (n)\}) = F_{n}$. This induces a strictly increasing function $\phi :\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$ and it can be verified that the subsequence $\left( \sum_{k=1}^{\phi (n)} e_{\pi (k)} \right)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ of $\left( \sum_{k=1}^{n} e_{\pi (k)} \right)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ does not converge to $f$.
Hopefully this makes a general approach to the problem clear. I leave it to you to fill in the rest of the details.
